# Will changing the system timezone convert all the time/date data into that timezone?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a record with purchase date of 1/1/2015 10:30 AM and my system timezone is UTC.
If I change the database timezone to Eastern Time. Would the purchase date for the existing record be automatically converted to Eastern Time? For example from 1/1/2015 10:30AM to 1/1/2015 5:30PAM.
Is this a feature in Oracle?

Also, is there a way to figure out what timezone the pruchase date was recorded in?

Comment: What is the data type of this column?  Are you storing the data in a `DATE` column?  A `TIMESTAMP`?  A `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`?  Or a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`?  Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your column's data type is `TIMESTAMP`, Oracle has no idea what time zone that timestamp is in.  The data won't change if you change the time zone on either the client or the server.  Similarly, there is no way to determine whether a particular value was intended to represent EST or MST or UTC.  Obviously, if you know that all your data is recorded in UTC, you could write an update statement that converted the data to a different time zone.

If you care about the time zone and want to do time zone conversions, you'd really want to store the time zone along with the date in a `TIMESTAMP WITH [LOCAL] TIME ZONE` column.  That makes it much easier to convert the data from one time zone to another.  If you use a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`, Oracle will automatically convert the data to the session's preferred time zone which allows different users to see the same data in their time zone without manipulating the data in the database.